# Область видимости в c++

Tags: c++

Имеется отрезок кода:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ( argc == 2 )
    {
        Alpha x(argv[1]);
    }
    if ( argc == 3 )
    {
        Alpha x(argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
    if ( argc != 2 && argc != 3 )
    {
        cout << "Arguments error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

который при попытке компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
user@user:~$ g++ lab4.cpp
lab4.cpp:100:18: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
  100 |     cout << x << endl;
      |             ^
```

Значит ли это, что x находится вне области видимости, и как лучше поступить в данной ситуации, не переписывая вывод в каждую отдельную проверку количества аргументов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Область видимости `x` ограничена фигурными скобками. В данной ситуации лучше вынести создание в отдельную функцию. Заодно потом можно будет написать для этого кода тесты.

```
inline Alpha Make_Alpha(int const argc, char * * const pp_args)
{
    if ( 2 == argc )
    {
        return Alpha{pp_args[1]};
    }
    if ( 3 == argc )
    {
        return Alpha{pp_args[1], pp_args[2]};
    }
    throw ::std::runtime_error{"Arguments error"};
}


int main (int const argc, char * * const pp_args)
{
    auto x{Make_Alpha(argc)};
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])    // Здесь x нет
{                                    // Здесь x нет
    if ( argc == 2 )                 // Здесь x нет
    {                                // Здесь x нет
        Alpha x(argv[1]);            // Здесь есть тот x, который argv[1]
    }                                // Здесь этот x приказал долго жить...
    if ( argc == 3 )                 // Здесь x нет
    {                                // Здесь x нет
        Alpha x(argv[1], argv[2]);   // Здесь есть тот x, который argv[1],argv[2]
    }                                // Здесь этот x приказал долго жить...
    if ( argc != 2 && argc != 3 )    // Здесь x нет
    {                                // Здесь x нет
        cout << "Arguments error" << endl;
        return 1;                    // Здесь x нет
    }                                // Здесь x нет
    cout << x << endl;               // Здесь x нет
```

Но допустим на минутку, что в последней строчке `x` есть. Вы - компилятор. Ответьте, **какой именно `x` выводить**? Первый или второй?

Comment: Но ведь аргументов может быть либо 2, либо 3 (либо больше). То есть одновременно будет существовать только 1 x.

Comment: Ну понятно, что один. Теоретически :) На самом деле ни одного. Но если бы был... ***Какой именно?*** Еще раз: вы — **компилятор**. Ваша задача решить вопрос сейчас (во время компиляции), а не когда код будет работать, и станет известно, один там аргумент или два. Сейчас вы этого не знаете. Ваши действия? Что вызывать?

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Alpha* y = nullptr;
    switch (argc)
    {
    case 2:
        y = new Alpha(argv[1]);
        break;
    case 3:
        y = new Alpha(argv[1], argv[2]);
        break;
    default:
        std::cerr << "Arguments error\n";
        return 1;
    }
    {
        Alpha& x = *y;
        // ...
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
    delete y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зря используете кучу. Лучше `std::optional`.